# Batch if exist error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i would like to add another instruction to this piece of code at this part `"if exist "%%d:\%folder%\" (echo Device was found on %%d:)"` so if that folder was found it would also do `set folderfound="%%d:\%folder%\"` is it possible to do something like that?
this is the code in full to show what im trying to do

```
:autodetect1    
set /p "folder=Folders Name that the photo's are in: "

    setlocal
    set folder=%1
    if "%folder%" == "" call :autodetect1
    cls
    for %%d in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
          if exist "%%d:\%folder%\" ( 
              echo Device was found on %%d: and set folderfound=%%d:\%folder%\
          ) else (
              echo Device was not found on %%d:
          )
    )
```

i was reading on forums and i found mention that you could use && to execute another command straight after could i use this inside the if exist?

Comment: looks as though "goto eof" should be "goto :eof" - but that makes the script terminate immediately after asking for a folder name. Not sure what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

using "&&" where you were using "and" in the following code seems to set the folderfound variable:

```
@echo off
:autodetect1
set /p "folder=Folders Name that the photo's are in: "
    rem goto :eof
    rem setlocal
    rem set folder=%1
    rem if "%folder%" == "" call :autodetect1
    rem cls
    for %%d in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
          if exist "%%d:\%folder%\" ( 
              echo Device was found on %%d: && set folderfound=%%d:\%folder%\
          ) else (
              echo Device was not found on %%d:
          )
    )
```

I've commented out bits I don't understand.

You need to understand what's happening here, go to http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx and scroll down to "Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols"